# Is it possible to get the total amount of bytes recieved from an http response(including headers)?

Tags: c#, http

For a school assignment I have to show that downloading a 1mb file 100 times is slower than downloading a 100mb file a single time.

The theory is: Downloading a 1mb file 100 times requires more total bytes because of the headers that are sent with it.

Now I wrote a script that times both scenarios and displays it in the console.
However, I would like to show the total amount of bytes recieved to show why it is taking longer.

This is what I have so far:

```
class TestClass
{
    private Stopwatch timer;
    private WebClient downloader;
    private TimeSpan elapsed;
    private string elapsedTime;

    public void SetUp()
    {
        timer = new Stopwatch();
        downloader = new WebClient();
    }

    public void StartTest()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting test");
        Console.WriteLine("Downloading 1mb file x100, please wait..."); 
        timer.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            downloader.DownloadFile("http://ftp.telfort.nl/pub/test/1megabyte.bin", @"c:\tempdownload\1mb.txt");
        }

        timer.Stop();
        elapsed = timer.Elapsed;

        // Format and display the TimeSpan value.
        elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
            elapsed.Hours, elapsed.Minutes, elapsed.Seconds,
            elapsed.Milliseconds / 10);

        Console.WriteLine("RunTime when downloading 1MB 100 times is: " + elapsedTime);

        // Now go for 100MB
        timer.Reset();
        Console.WriteLine("Downloading 100mb file 1x, please wait...");
        timer.Start();
        downloader.DownloadFile("http://ftp.telfort.nl/pub/test/100megabyte.bin", @"c:\tempdownload\100mb.txt");
        timer.Stop();

        elapsed = timer.Elapsed;

        // Format and display the TimeSpan value.
        elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
            elapsed.Hours, elapsed.Minutes, elapsed.Seconds,
            elapsed.Milliseconds / 10);
        Console.WriteLine("RunTime when downloading 100MB 1 time is: " + elapsedTime);

        // Finally
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

**EDIT:** I think the title may have been misleading...

Comment: Sure.

On the webserver, place two files: One of 1mb and another of 100mb

Now, time how long they take to download. Preferably with code.

At the start of the download put:

    DateTime StartTime = DateTime.Now;

...and when a download finishes:

    long MillisecondsTaken = StartTime.Ticks() - DateTime.Now.Ticks();

You might want to repeat the experiment a few times, say ten times and plop the data on a graph.

Comment: @Knickerless-Noggins - when you check the code, you see that's exactly what he is doing, except with a Stopwatch, wich is way better dan DateTime.Now

Comment: @CodeCaster I would like to calculate the total amount of bytes recieved from the _entire_ response, _including_ the response headers. Not just the amount of bytes from the recieved files

Comment: I think the theory is flawed. I believe the additional time spent transmitting the headers for the smaller file will be eclipsed by the time required by the overhead of opening and closing the smaller file 100 times. To truly see the difference taking into account only the additional transmit time for the headers, you'd have to simply take the 1mb file single download time and multiply by 100. This would exclude the file open/close time from the test.

Comment: @Hans Kesting Keep your hair on. In addition Thomas can calculate number of bytes by dividing the number of megabytes by 1024

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to measure the size of the entire reponse.

The HTTP classes that the BCL offers (HttpWebResponse, WebClient, HttpClient) do not have a way to extract the entire request or response message size (including status-line, response-headers and message-body).

You can emulate this by counting the length of the header's names and values, but due to folding and the condensation of multiple headers into one dictionary entry this won't be entirely accurate.

You can easily make a trivial HTTP GET request using sockets though, and simply make an HTTP/1.0 request to let the server close the connection after sending the entire response (so you won't have to re-implement an HTTP client over sockets).

But the headers are not your issue. Over 100 HTTP requests for a file of 1 MB, the request and response headers will account for a measly ~ 150 bytes per request, or a marginal 15 KB for the total transfer of 100 MB of payload.

The real delay will be caused by the creation of 100 separate TCP connections, and their typical slow start.